# -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true where to add this in jmeter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, webdriver, jmeter

I am getting issue while hit web-service in jmeter.

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

After surfing got solution to add this flag

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

but i don't know in which file should i add this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the jmeter.sh/jmeter.bat

```
##   ==============================================
##   Environment variables:
##   JVM_ARGS - optional java args, e.g. -Dprop=val
##
##   ==============================================
```

if you are on linux

export JVM_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

on windows

set JVM_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"